# Kotlin Multiplatform Library using Cocoapods with multiple ios targets

Tags: ios, kotlin, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I have a Kotlin Multiplatform Library which supports Android, ios(arm64, simArm64). I recently added a cocoapod dependancy of the ios target (Analytics).

When using only one ios target(for example arm64) then the library compiles and works as expected.

When I add the additional ios target simArm64, i get the error that the compiler: `Unresolved reference: cocoapods`

My guess this is because .dependsOn doesnt play nicely with cocoapods, has anybody come across this issue and how they got around it?

Here is an example of my build gradle.

```
    iosSimulatorArm64 {
        binaries.framework {
            baseName = frameworkName
            xcf.add(this)
        }
    }
    iosArm64("ios") {
        binaries.framework {
            baseName = frameworkName
            xcf.add(this)
        }
    }
    cocoapods {
        ios.deploymentTarget = "10.0"
        summary = "Some description for a Kotlin/Native module"
        homepage = "Link to a Kotlin/Native module homepage"

        pod("Analytics") {
            version = "~> 4.1.6"
            moduleName = "Segment"
            source = git("https://github.com/Reedyuk/analytics-ios.git") {
                branch = "master"
            }
        }
    }
....
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor_version")
            }
        }
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(iosMain)
        val iosTest by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(iosTest)
```

Comment: What did your config look like before you added cocoapods? I can see multiple issues here. With `cocoapods`, you shouldn't also configure `binaries.framework` in your targets, as cocoapods does that. Also, you have `iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(iosMain)` but `iosArm64` has the name specified in the target declaration. That *probably* works, but it's kind of an asymetric config which can complicate things. I'd personally set up both targets to depend on `iosMain`.

Comment: Probably, source sets hierarchy makes everything confusing, as there is a "leaf" platform-specific source set being also a dependency for another source set. I would recommend providing an intermediate source set like here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-share-on-platforms.html#configure-the-hierarchical-structure-manually. Also, maybe the problem is just about the `cocoapods` block being nested into the wrong place. It should be under the `kotlin` block.

Comment: @KevinGalligan - the config was exactly the same but without the cocoapods definition. This has worked fine for me in the past.
Your solution to create a seperate iosMain and then have them all depend on might work so i will give it a try BUT i still think that it should work the way i have tried to make it work.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev - cocoapods has to exist in the kotlin block otherwise it fails, i assume because its kotlin.cocoapods { }
It seems that all proposed solutions are to create a iOS main target that all the others inherit from but im not sure if i will get the same issue.

Comment: I made the ios targets depend on an iosMain but the error is still the same.
I added: kotlin.mpp.enableCInteropCommonization=true
which seems to build successfully, but then any consuming projects of library has an error
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SEGAnalytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in result.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SEGAnalyticsConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in result.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Comment: How are you consuming the result framework, also by the CocoaPods machinery? I'm asking because if its not true, one would have to add Analytics dependency into the app too, because the framework Kotlin Multiplatform produces won't have these symbols.

Comment: Good question, which im still investigating.
One issue i have is that once i have published my library, trying to use this in another KMM library, seems to be causing a problem.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev yes, if you are to consume the library directly into the native layer, then you will need to include the required native lib.
This is the purpose of the wrapper library, for which im not sure how else you can do, without going down this route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further inspection, i managed to find a solution.

In the cocoapods extension there is a 'framework' field, in addition adding

`kotlin.mpp.enableCInteropCommonization=true`

to the gradle.properties file

You will have something that looks like this:

```
kotlin {
    android {
        publishAllLibraryVariants()
    }

    val xcf = XCFramework()
    iosSimulatorArm64 {
        binaries.framework {
            baseName = frameworkName
            xcf.add(this)
        }
    }
    iosArm64("ios") {
        binaries.framework {
            baseName = frameworkName
            xcf.add(this)
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api("com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.10.3")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting

        val iosMain by getting {}
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(iosMain)
        val iosTest by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(iosTest)
    }

}

kotlin {
    cocoapods {
        ios.deploymentTarget = "10.0"
        summary = "Some description for a Kotlin/Native module"
        homepage = "Link to a Kotlin/Native module homepage"
        framework {  }
        pod("Analytics") {
            version = "~> 4.1.6"
            moduleName = "Segment"
            source = git("https://github.com/Reedyuk/analytics-ios.git") {
                branch = "master"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I'm wondering if `cocoapods` automatically detects your XC framework. Because it seems there is no connection between those two in the code snippet above.